# Clojure stack for Video Chat

Tags: clojure, video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture

Is there a standard framework (like Ring/Enlive/Domina/Compojure/ClojureScriptOne) for doing Video Chat in Clojure? Googling tends to bring up *videos* about Clojure rather than a framework for doing VideoChat in Clojure.

An example application would be say -- one is trying to build something like ChatRoulette in Clojure. What would be the right framework to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a streaming server in clojure or you can use Red5 server as the streaming server and write video chat application on top of it (Red5 is Java based so writing apps on top of it in clojure should not be a problem)